# getting webpage data in XML format using CURL

Tags: html, xml, http, curl, web

I am attempting to get data in XML as well as HTML format using curl.

```
 curl --data "<xml>" --header "Content-Type: xml"  http://example.com

 curl --data "<html>" --header "Content-Type: html"  http://example.com
```

Both cases I get the following output.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #f0f0f2;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

    }
    div {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 5em auto;
        padding: 50px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 1em;
    }
    a:link, a:visited {
        color: #38488f;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 700px) {
        body {
            background-color: #fff;
        }
        div {
            width: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
            border-radius: 0;
            padding: 1em;
        }
    }
    </style>    
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <h1>Example Domain</h1>
    <p>This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
    domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
    <p><a href="http://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
</div>
</body>
```

Which is clear HTML.How can I get the data in XML and in JSON too if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask to the server to return you xml or json, but its up to the server whether they will return you data in that format or not(also, the server must have that mechanism implemented).

You can do a request for xml in this way:

```
-H 'Accept: application/xml'
```

For json:

```
-H 'Accept: application/json'
```

FYI: example.com doesn't have that implemented. So you'll always get html from them.

Comment: is there a site that does? I tried with yahoo.com and google.com it seesm to give the same result.?

Comment: I didn't find any. May be there is! Its very easy to make one.